# Trace of the square root inside commutation property

Tags: matrices, radicals, matrix-calculus, trace, symmetric-matrices

I checked this statement numerically even if I cannot find it anywhere and didn't manage to prove it:
$$\text{Tr}(\sqrt{B^TB})=\text{Tr}(\sqrt{BB^T}) \qquad \forall B\in M_{n,r}(\mathbb{R}).$$
The result is well-known without the square root, but here we have one and the matrix $B$ is not necessarily square. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are (possibly rectangular) matrices such that $AB$ and $BA$ make sense, then the eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) of the larger matrix are the same as the eigenvalues of the smaller matrix, modulo adding a bunch of zero eigenvalues. This shows that the two positive-semidefinite symmetric operators $B^T B$ and $B B^T$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$. The principal square root of each of these matrices will therefore have eigenvalues $\sqrt{\lambda_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{\lambda_k}$, and so their traces are equal.